# How to use a query result or column value to define a select column name?

Tags: oracle

How can I use a column value as a column name. I've tried this:

```
SELECT TableX.(
SELECT OdTable.columnamecell
from OdTable
where 1 =1
AND OdTable.KeyValue = TableX.SomeValue 
) as MyValue
,TableX.OtherValue as OtherValue
, TableX.SomeValue
from TableX
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Or to say it another way: Can I use a table column value as a column name for another query or sub-query?

To clarify: The table: OdTable has a column with values that are the column name in another table.

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL, SQL Server, or Oracle?

Comment: tag this with your ACTUAL database, not a soup of every possible DB. an answer for oracle would be utterly useless if you're using mysql.

Comment: I think you want pivoting, but I can't say for sure. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and Yes. You can't do this with "standard" SQL; all table and column names must be known, as literals, when the query is compiled; they can't be provided at runtime. What you want is called "dynamic SQL"; sometimes it is the only solution to a problem, but most of the time it is used when it is not necessary. It has several disadvantages (security risk, performance penalty, difficulty to maintain, ...)